# I am searching for the English thesaurus for all words we used id English to add to elastic search synonym list. Where can I get it?

Tags: elasticsearch, nlp

I want list of synonyms words for all English words..where can I get this? I need to add then in Elastic search synonym list to get more efficient results.

Comment: You might want to look at language based built in analyzers provided with elastic. Have a look [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html).

Comment: thanks!.....but I want the list of all synonyms words present in English so that I can add those to   "synonyms_path" : "analysis/synonym.txt" this file

Comment: Thesaurus would be very wide set of synonyms. Can you share the use case where you want full set of english thesaurus.

Comment: @Dimple is synonyms not enabled by default when language analyzer added? do we have to explicitly add them?

Comment: @Rajeev  yes we need to add synonym list explicitly.  like this  "synonyms_path": "my_synonyms.txt"...we need to put the synonym list text file in config folder of Elasticsearch

Answer (score 1):

The most well-known thesaurus with English synonyms is [WordNet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/).

If you want to access it from Python, you can use [nltk](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-get-synonyms-antonyms-from-nltk-wordnet-in-python) for this purpose.

```
import nltk
nltk.download('wordnet')

from nltk.corpus import wordnet 
synset = wordnet.synsets("cake")
print('Synonyms: ' + '; '.join(sorted({lemma.name() for sense in synset for lemma in sense.lemmas()})))
# Synonyms: bar; cake; coat; patty
```

Comment: Thanks..this is what I was looking for